# What if I don't want type safety?

Tags: c#, vba, com-interop, equality, type-safety

I'm writing a little VBA IDE add-in, and there's a COM-visible C# class called `AssertClass`, with an `AreEqual` method that goes like this:

```
public void AreEqual(object value1, object value2, string message = null)
{
    if (value1.Equals(value2))
    {
        AssertHandler.OnAssertSucceeded();
    }
    else
    {
        AssertHandler.OnAssertFailed("AreEqual", message);
    }
}
```

---

When the client VBA code calls it like this, all works as expected:

```vb
'@TestMethod
Public Sub TestMethod1()
    'compares two identical Integer (Int16) values:
    Assert.AreEqual 2, 2
End Sub
```

[image: TestMethod1 passes]

However when the client VBA code passes different types, it fails:

```vb
'@TestMethod
Public Sub TestMethod2()
    'compares identically-valued Long (Int32) and Integer (Int16) values:
    Assert.AreEqual CLng(2), 2
End Sub
```

[image: TestMethod2 fails]

---

When `TestMethod2` calls `Assert.AreEqual`, the .NET code receives an `int` and a `short` - which is correct... but I don't want to put it on the client VBA code to make sure it's passing the same types - I'd want all these calls to result in a succeeding assertion:

```vb
Assert.AreEqual CByte(2), 2 'fails
Assert.AreEqual CInt(2), 2  'passes
Assert.AreEqual CLng(2), 2  'fails
Assert.AreEqual CSng(2), 2  'fails
Assert.AreEqual CDbl(2), 2  'fails
Assert.AreEqual CCur(2), 2  'fails
```

After all, VBA isn't as strict as C# when it comes to type safety and equality checks:

```vb
?CByte(2) = 2, CInt(2) = 2, CLng(2) = 2, CSng(2) = 2, CDbl(2) = 2, CCur(2) = 2
True          True          True          True          True          True
```

---

How can I formulate my `AreEqual` C# function so as to... somehow avoid forcing type safety into the VBA client code? I cannot assume that the VBA client code is going to pass numeric values - the method needs to also work with `String` and `Date` values.

I'm stumped. Is my only option to document the fact that *types matter*?

Using C# 4.5 in VS 2013 Express.

Comment: Not to take away anything that you are trying to accomplish and maybe this doesn't work at all for your design, but why not have a more generic method like `Assert.IsTrue()`? Then your VBA examples should work: `Assert.IsTrue(CByte(2) = 2)`

Comment: @TyCobb The `AssertClass` has `AreEqual`, `AreNotEqual`, `AreNotSame`, `AreSame`, `Fail`, `Inconclusive`, `IsFalse`, `IsNothing`, `IsNotNothing` and `IsTrue` methods. Only `AreEqual` (and `AreNotEqual`) are problematic; I omitted the other methods for brievety ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark (haven't worked with VBA & C# combination), but try this and see if it works:

```
public void AreEqual(object value1, object value2, string message = null)
{
    bool convertedOk = true;
    object value2Converted;

    try
    {
         value2Converted = Convert.ChangeType(value2, value1.GetType());
    }
    catch 
    {
         convertedOk = false;
    }

    if (convertedOk && value1.Equals(value2Converted))
    {
        AssertHandler.OnAssertSucceeded();
    }
    else
    {
        AssertHandler.OnAssertFailed("AreEqual", message);
    }
}
```

Idea being that you change type of second value that that of first so they now become "more compatilbe" for comparison.

*EDIT*:
   Updated answer with try/catch handling as suggested by comments. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, convert it! (facepalm) ...now the actual fix requires a `try/catch` block to ensure conversion is indeed possible, but this answer definitely put me on the right track. Thanks! http://i.stack.imgur.com/IH72b.png

Comment: Interesting answer. This will probably need to be wrapped up in a try block in case value two cant be converted.

Comment: Note: after giving it some more thought, I'll keep the `AssertClass` methods type-safe. Much, much simpler, no side effects, and no edge cases. Consider `AreEqual 300, CByte(30)` versus `AreEqual CByte(30), 300` - one blows up, the other passes. And I'm not even mentioning what happens to converted `Boolean` values..